# residuals of fractional probit regression

Tags: r, regression, probit

I have a data set whose dependent variable is confined to the range [0,1]. I modeled it using fractional probit regression in R `(model=glm(Y~X1+X2,family=quasibinomial(link=probit),data=mydata))`

When I checked the residuals *(using command `model.residuals`)* I found that it was not equal to the difference in actual and predicted values. Can someone explain where I went wrong.
*(predicted value were obtained using model.fitted.values)*

*P.S. This is not a programming question and hence I posted it here. I want to understand why the residuals are not equal to difference between actual and predicted.*